# Emacs attach an action to any key pressed

Tags: emacs, elisp

Suppose, I have the code:

```
(defun dummy ()
      (interactive)
      (message "aaa"))

(local-set-key (kbd "<left>") 'dummy)
```

When you click `<left>` key in the current buffer, it will print "aaa".

Is it possible to attach this action to any key pressed?

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to accomplish... It sounds a little but un-emacsy to make a keypress do something that typically don't happen when you press a key in a window and/or buffer.

Comment: @Lindydancer I am trying to make latex compiling more efficient. When there is a bug while compiling, pdflatex stops and I want to immediately see the error and close the window, pressing any key. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887855/elisp-sentinel-on-process-waiting-for-input I was told, that I can't track, that the process is stopped and waiting for response. I thought, maybe at least, I could attach a keypress hook when creating a window.

Comment: Do you want the action to be attached to the *window* or the *buffer*? (surely the latter! a window can display any buffer)

Comment: @phils Yes, buffer. Edited the question

Comment: I don't think a hook is the right way to do this. When you start the latex compilation, you have full control over the compilation buffer. You can then simply create a local key binding. Besides, you have been misinformed about processes. You can create a so-called *sentinel* that will be called when the process dies.

Comment: @Lindydancer I know, that I can create such sentinel. But my process doesn't die. It just stops with a message: "Error, input something", waiting for the user input. Can you give an example of a local key binding for one buffer?

Comment: Try ´(local-set-key (kbd "SPC") 'my-function)`. Also, you could install a process filter, looking for the "Error, input something" text. If there already is a process filter installed, things are a little bit more complicated, as your filter will have to forward whatever it gets to the original filter.

Comment: @Lindydancer is it possible to attach it to any key press?

Comment: @user4035, not that I know of, unfortunately... (Of course, you could assign it to every key on the keyboard, but that's not a very clean solution.)

Comment: @phils I found a partial solution to the original question and have edited it. Maybe you know, how to attach an action to any key?

Comment: When you change the question as much as you just did, isn't it better to create a new question? The comments that were made above simply doesn't make sense in the light of the new question...

Comment: @Lindydancer I asked the moderator on meta: "change it or create a new one"? He said: "edit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
(defun dummy ()
      (interactive)
      (message "aaa"))

(local-set-key [t] 'dummy)
```

Comment: It does not work for me, the function is just never called disregarding what I press.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really envisage the use case for this, but it sounds like the "default key binding" keymap mechanism would facilitate it.

For starters, take a look at:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Format of Keymaps` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Searching Keymaps` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Here's [one usecase](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80747/c-arglist-intro-indent-based-on-the-indentation-of-previous-line/80768#80768). Basically, the problem comes down to having a function `foo` that gets called by some foreign code after you pressed some key `X`. And the problem is that `foo` might get called many times by that "foreign code" but you want to do something only the first time it got called upon pressing the `X`. And you can't add a binding to `X` because `X` can be any key. Binding to "any key pressed" allows to drop state so you know when will be the 1st call.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: you can try `post-command-hook` *(or `pre-command-hook`)* which is very close to what you desire:

```lisp
(defun dummy ()
  (interactive)
  (message "aaa"))
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'dummy)
```

**Longer explanation**:

The closest thing that I know of is `post-command-hook`. Emacs manual has [the following text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Commands.html):

> […] Emacs does not assign meanings to keys directly. Instead, Emacs assigns meanings to named *commands*, and then gives keys their meanings by *binding* them to commands.

I interpret that as "there's no way to bind to every key", because the design is that you're supposed to deal with commands rather than keys.

So with that said, there are `post-command-hook` and `pre-command-hook` which are called every time a key triggering an action *(including one that prints a "<kbd>key</kbd> is undefined")* is pressed. Though, for command to get executed *(and hence for hook to get triggered)* you don't necessarily have to press a key.

All in all, I think it should cover usecases of "binding to any key" just as well. Just make sure not to put there anything CPU-heavy, because this function will be called on every letter, as you wanted.